# iPhone Application Development: Built in applications enhanced

Tags: ios, emoji, emoticons

I just saw an iPhone application that enhances the built in "messages" application to send emotions. What this application does is that it extends the functionality of the Keyboard that appears in notes or messages application, and user can send emotion icons as messages. This application doesn't work when the emotions are sent to other mobile devices (it works only with iPhone), but that's not important. What I'm wondering is, how they did that (extended the built in keyboard)? Do we have API's that let you extend the functionality like this?

Comment: You want to know - so you can create an app like that too? And put some more junk on the store?

There are places that explain how to do that... but I really don't think your question is appropriate, nor is my answer...

Comment: Dear natanavra - not everything is about making money! some of us try to wonder the mysteries and learn the solutions.  i certainly can't force the information out of you. Thanks for dropping a non-helpful comment anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are part of the font set. called Emoji icons.

> Apple's latest iPhone OS update
>   brought cute little "Emoji" icons for
>   Asian markets

To use them you need to use the (font) character code for each letter / emoji. I don't know what they are, but a quick google returns, abide a lot of spam, some codes worth trying. A quick script could be made to incrementally loop through each character code, thus finding them all.

A quick google:

```
&#xe001;
&#xe002;
&#xe003;
&#xe004;
&#xe005;
&#xe006;
```

Comment: Note that Apple banned applications which enabled Emoji back in March, but some appear to have slipped back into the store: http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2009/04/iphone_emoji_apps_back_in_app_store_someone_probably_rejoices-2/ .  Relying on this functionality in your application would probably be a little risky.

Comment: @Brad Larson, thanks for sharing this news.

I'm not actually interested in incorporating this, I'm just wondering how the developer must have done that? Though some undocumented API, maybe?

@Ross, I believe the entity representation of all those Emoji icons are in Japanese language, even for simple one's like : ) and : (. And, it makes sense if iPhone OS support this. But apparently, it doesn't come built in. Emoji application is available on the App Store, and installing this adds this new panel to the default keyboard.

Comment: @Ross: `&#xe...;` instead of `&#ex...;`.

Comment: @KennyTM: Thanks, I've updated my answer. Like the fact there characters have to marked up as code.